# iText PDF library - What units are the return values for PdfPtable.getTotalHeight() or calculateHeights() in? Points?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

[The method in question](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#calculateHeights%28boolean%29)

I imagine it's points since the library uses that for some other values, but if anyone has used this and knows for sure it would be nice.

Comment: Wow. That seems like such a critical oversight in the documentation that was I inspired to go get a SourceForge account and update the Javadoc. Sadly SourceForge is down now... hopefully the urge will remain once it's back up.

Comment: For reference, see page 8 in the book, iText In Action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Points.   1/72 of an inch.  This is the standard PDF unit of measurement...

Unless a relatively new PDF feature is used to change that for the current document.  Unless you're working with architectural drawings, or geospatial data I wouldn't worry about it.